# Install pip with specefic python version

Tags: python, pip

I am building a ubuntu docker image that is going to run my python application, and I have some libraries that require python <= 3.6 to work otherwise it will throw errors.

My problem is that when I install pip, it will always automatically use python 3.8, and I'm not sure how to let pip use an older version of python, this is the installation in my `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \ 
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-add-repository universe && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libmysqlclient-dev \
    netcat \
    python3 \
    python-dev \
    build-essential \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-pip \
    supervisor && \
    pip install -U pip setuptools && \
   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I tried to change `python3-pip` by just `python-pip` but when I run it it gives me the following error

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

I've tried a lot of solutions but always the same problem

Comment: probably run `python3.6 -m pip ...` for (in example) version 3.6

Comment: How do you install Python 3.6 in your Dockerfile in the first place, if there is no corresponding pip 3.6, but pip 3.8 instead?

Comment: Oh, probably with the deadsnakes archive?

Comment: Why not start Dockerfile with "FROM python:3.6-buster" ?

Comment: @phd because I need other Ubuntu elements

Comment: @gXLg Thanks. that helped resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Docker, if `python3.6` is the python you need, you can do:
`python3.6 -m pip install`

In Docker right now obviously `python3` is pointing to Python 3.8 so you must first install `python3.6` and find out how to call it (`python3.6` or `python3`). You might need to compile it from source and probably create some symbolic link. This can get very ugly to do inside a Docker, but you can try to write a shell script with all commands and to run the shell script inside a Docker. Or if you are lucky you may [find a ready Python3.6 Docker package](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) that works for you and `apt-get install` it instead of `python3` the same way as you do now.